# If function error. Not equals to function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am writing this program and it works fine,
I leave it for sometime and the code stops working.

Please help me in this function;
Here is the code:

```
acceptables = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]
try :
    toss = input("Toss a number from 1 to 6 (10 included): ")
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid")

if toss != acceptables:
    print("Illegal Numbers!")
    time.sleep(2)
    exit()
else:
    pass
```

So what should happen is, the user will enter a number in *toss* and it will check
if the number is from *acceptables*, if not it will quit the program.

But now, I entered number **that is** in *acceptables* and it still ends up showing
"Illegal Number" and quits the program.

Is this a new python3 update or something that I missed out on? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two problems:

1. `toss = input(...)` returns a string, but you want to compare that value to `int`s. Try a type conversion: `toss = int(toss)` to transform your `str` from `"1"` to `1`.
2. You're checking if the number is in the list using `if toss != acceptables:` which will always be `False` because an `int` (or `str` at the moment) will never be equal to a `list`. You want to check if `toss` is in the list of `acceptables`. Try this instead: `if toss in acceptables:`

Comment: ```
acceptables = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]
try :
    toss = int(input("Toss a number from 1 to 6 (10 included): "))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid")

if toss in acceptables:
    print("")
else:
    ("Illegal Numbers!")
    time.sleep(1)
    exit()
```
Is this better?

Comment: Assuming that the indentation is there, yes, that should work

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues. First, this line:

```
toss = input("Toss a number from 1 to 6 (10 included): ")
```

will store the string value of whatever you submit into `toss`. You likely want this line to read:

```
toss = int(input("Toss a number from 1 to 6 (10 included): "))
```

to ensure you get an integer or a `ValueError` in the case the user types a non-integer string.

Secondly, this line:

```
if toss != acceptables:
```

is checking if `toss`, what would be an int, is not equal to a list, essentially doing this: `if 5 != [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]`. You instead likely want this to read:

```
if toss not in acceptables:
```

To check if this number is in your list of acceptable numbers.